# Imap Idle channel adaptor on load balanced Servers

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below configuration for my incoming mail adapter. Everything is working fine when application is running on a single server. But when I deploy the application in a load balanced servers listening to the same mail box then the mail is being read in all the server.
How to handle this scenario? Are there any specific configuration to handle such scenarios.

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter
    id="customAdapter"
    store-uri="${mail.protocol}://${mail.username}:${mail.password}@${mail.host}:${mail.port}/${mail.folder}"
    channel="recieveEmailChannel" auto-startup="true"
    should-delete-messages="false" 
    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties" 
    mail-filter-expression="subject matches '(?i).*Email Notification.*'" />

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.ssl.trust">${mail.ssl.trust}</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.usesocketchannels">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" expression="@emailService.process(payload)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One of them is a [Leader Election](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#leadership-event-handling) by the same `role` for the `<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>`.

And another is a [Idempotent Receiver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver) to track duplicates in the shared `MetadataStore`.

Comment: This is available for the latest Spring integration version 4+ onwards.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Is that a question?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am still on spring integration version 2.2.6 and won’tbe able to upgrade as it is a part of the framework. So is there a way i can achieve this in the older version insteadof writing a custom code.

Comment: Ok. So, you can use the `filter` based on the shared database to avoid duplicates